# VBA: Is it possible to use cell values to activate a similarly named tab?

Tags: excel, vba

This may be pretty basic but I haven't had success yet.

I have a block of data within a range on workbook 1.
Each cell has a value that corresponds to tab names of workbook 2.

How can I use these cell's value to activate the proper corresponding tab on workbook 2?

### The code is on another computer sorry no examples right now.

I tried so far setting a variable equal to the cell's value, but can't seem to translate it into a workbook object for calling the tabs.

thanks!

Comment: If `ws1` is the first worksheet, and `wb2` is the 2nd workbook, then something like `wb2.Worksheets(ws1.Range("A1").Value)`.

Comment: I made slight changes, but the idea worked! thank you! 

wb2.Worksheets(ws1.Range("A1").Value).Activate

Answer (score 0):

Assume your tab name is in `Sheet1` in `Workbook1` then we can use the following method:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Tab_Caller()
    
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim sSheetName As String

    'set the workbook objects
    Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
    Set wb2 = Workbooks("MySecondWOrkbook.xlsx")

    'set the worksheet
    Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Sheet1")
    sSheetName = ws1.Range("A1").Value

    'Activate the required tab in wb2 using value in ws1
    wb2.Sheets(sSheetName).Selct
    wb2.Sheets(sSheetName).Activate

End SUb
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a WB1.xlsm with this data:

[image]

and a WB2.xlsx with these three sheets:

[image]

both open, positioning the cursor on the AA cell as above and running this code:

```vb
Workbooks("WB2.xlsx").Sheets(ActiveCell.Value).Activate
```

Will activate WB2 and activate the AA sheet.